# Async function order of execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an async function that is written like:

```
pool.query(`select id from table1`)
  .then(rows=>{
    pool.query(`selectQuery1`)
      .then(rows=>{
        return pool.query(`selectQuery2`)
      })
    .then(rows=>{
      console.log('First')
      return pool.query(`selectQuery3`)
    })
  })
  .then(rows=>{
    console.log('Second')
    return pool.query(`selectQuery4`)
  })
```

I was thinking that the final `.then` should fire after everything else. But the `console.log` shows

```
second
first
```

I do not understand why this is happening

Comment: The query in your first `then` is completely independent from the outer query. It (almost always) won't complete before the outer query has returned its rows.

Comment: `return pool.query(...).then(...)`

Comment: You didn't chain them all together into one sequential chain.  You created two parallel and independent chains so it's just a race which one finished first.  Add a `return` in front of the second `pool.query()` and things will change.

Comment: Also, your indendation levels are wrong, which makes spotting the issue harder. The `.then(rows...)` on line 7 should be indented more, so that it is flush with the `.then(rows...)` on line 4. The way you have it written makes it seem like the intent is to have those two blocks run as part of the 2nd query, but that is not what the code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't chain them all together into one sequential chain.

You created two parallel and independent chains so it's just a race which one finished first.

Add a `return` in front of the second `pool.query()` and things will change like this:

```
pool.query(`select id from table1`)
  .then(rows=>{
    // **** add return here ****
    return pool.query(`selectQuery1`)
      .then(rows=>{
        return pool.query(`selectQuery2`)
      })
    .then(rows=>{
      console.log('First')
      return pool.query(`selectQuery3`)
    })
  })
  .then(rows=>{
    console.log('Second')
    return pool.query(`selectQuery4`)
  });
```

By leaving out that `return`, you created a whole separate promise chain that is independent from the parent chain and thus it's just a race to see which one finishes first so it will end up depending upon the speed of the various operations in the two chains and may not even be the same order of completion each time you run it.

FYI, if you truly want sequential actions, then it's generally better to flatten your chain into:

```
fn().then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...)
```

Not:

```
fn1().then(function() {
    return fn2(...).then(...).then(...)
}).then(...)
```

As the former is a lot clearer what you're trying to do.  If you have logical branching (which you don't show), then you are sometimes forced away from the flat design.

Your code after flattening would look like this:

```
pool.query(`select id from table1`).then(rows=>{
    return pool.query(`selectQuery1`);
}).then(rows => {
    return pool.query(`selectQuery2`);    
}).then(rows => {
    return pool.query(`selectQuery3`);
}).then(rows => {
    return pool.query(`selectQuery4`);
}).then(rows => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Or, using async/wait, it might be even cleaner:

```
try {
    let rows1 = await pool.query(`select id from table1`);
    let rows2 = await pool.query(`selectQuery1`);
    let rows2 = await pool.query(`selectQuery2`);
    let rows3 = await pool.query(`selectQuery3`);
    let rows4 = await pool.query(`selectQuery4`);
    console.log("done");
} catch(e) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

---

FYI, failing to return a promise chain from inside a `.then()` handler is nearly always a bug because there's no way to communicate success or failure to the outside world.

The only situation I've ever seen where it was a correct decision is in some sort of fire and forget operation like perhaps closing a file where there's nothing to do differently if the operation fails and you wish the rest of the operation to proceed normally and not wait for completion.  But this is the rare exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Added examples of flattened code with `.then()` and with `async/await`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the technical issue is that you are missing a return statement. However, you are also using a non-starding style of indenting which makes your intent less clear and the error harder to spot.

Here is your code with some added line breaks and indent changes. The idea is that, a) chained method calls should alwasy be multi-line, with each chain at the same indendation level, and b) arrow functions that use blocks should always be indentended one level higher than the scope they exist in.

```
pool
    .query(`select id from table1`)
    .then(rows => {
        // FIX: add return
        pool
            .query(`selectQuery1`)
            .then(rows => {
                return pool.query(`selectQuery2`);
            })
            .then(rows => {
                console.log('First');
                return pool.query(`selectQuery3`);
            });
    })
    .then(rows => {
        console.log('Second');
        return pool.query(`selectQuery4`);
    });
```

When displayed this way, it is easier to spot that there is one inner use of `pool` that does not have a `return` in front of it.